# Error after INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

I've the following code:

```
$salt=uniqid(mt_rand(), false);
#Add data to tables
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES('$user', '".hash('sha512',$pass+$salt)."', '$salt', '$cookie_value')");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO passwordreset VALUES('$user', NULL, NULL)");
#cookie creation
#.....
#cookie update
mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET cookie='$cookie_value' WHERE user='$user'");
```

I sanitize data from form using these functions:

```
$var = htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
```

Today I logged into phpMyAdmin and I saw that passwords **and salts** for all users are the same.
Don't remind me about deprecated mysql_* I know it, that's just quick draft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatenation in PHP uses `.` not `+`. Thus:

`hash('sha512',$pass+$salt)`

Should be

```
hash('sha512',$pass.$salt) // or
hash('sha512',"${pass}${salt}")
```

Comment: sounds weird, but yesterday everything was nice, how can it be?

Comment: Maybe it just appeared fine yesterday and since getting more accounts the error has become more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This is PHP, `$pass+$salt` should be `$pass . $salt`

Comment: Does this produce the problem?

Comment: @riwette Yes, `"a"+"b"` give you `0`. So most values are just the result of `hash('sha512', 0)`

Comment: sounds weird, but yesterday everything was nice, how can it be?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things I would comment on your current code:

1. Using the `+` operator (as opposed to `.`) on two strings results in the sum of both values cast to integer (if a string is not numeric it's cast to `int(0)`); when it's passed to `hash()` it gets cast to a string again, so your passwords will typically all be `sha512("0")`. I'm not sure why your salts all have the same value though, unless the column data type is `INT` in your database.
2. You can use `uniqid(mt_rand(), true)` to collect more entropy, resulting in a better salt.
3. You should hash passwords with a dedicated password hash, such as the BlowFish option in [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/crypt) (make sure your column width is big enough); this way you can get rid of the salt column and you can choose how much work is required to verify the hash in a backward compatible manner.
4. The cookie column is for an auto-login feature I assume? It's better to create a separate table for this containing a randomized string as the primary key and a foreign key to your users table. This way you can support auto-login from multiple browsers.

Comment: is it possible to use unique salt for every blowfish hash? And how do I check user password?

Comment: @riwette yes, you can add your `$salt` variable as part of the second argument; please read the documentation thoroughly btw :) checking a password is easy; `$hash === crypt($password, $hash)`

Answer (score 0):

error here

```
$pass+$salt
```

should be

```
$pass.$salt
```

. is used for string catenation in php